# how to make many to many Audio Stream?

Tags: javascript, cordova, streaming, audio-streaming

I am working on a project by **cordova, mongodb, node.js**  .
The Project Idea is To give a service to each client to stream his voice to other clients , it's look like a radio station , when a client start talking 
The other clients connected to previous client   receive his voice  ,

Where I could start ?
 should I look for  a server audio streaming hosting 
or what

thanks

Comment: See [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: How many clients, and how many listeners per-client?  What sort of platforms are you targeting?  If it's only a couple listeners per person streaming, WebRTC is a very cheap way to do this.

Comment: no sir , WebRTC 's quality  doesn't service me in my situation . my clients number  as I plan could be a huge  , and every client listeners could reach 1000 . 
I need the app look like Facebook video streaming live but Audio !!